# Как удалить все пакеты из конкретного репозитория?

Tags: centos

Нужно удалить все пакеты из конкретного репозитория, так как есть подозрение того, что из-за кривого пакета стал работать ооооочень долго PHP в связке с Apache.

Причем надо удалить все без остатков, переустанавливать сервер по новой не хочется, т.к. только первоначальная настройка занимает более 4 часов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все просто! Смотрим `yum history` и далее делаем там где надо `yum undo #`, где # номер операции yum. В большинстве это решает проблему установленных и обновленных корявых или не подходящих пакетов.